# How to run two media players synchronously on a form?

Tags: c#, media-player

I want to run two media players in one form. The same video will be played on both media players and will be played at the same time. There should be no seconds difference between the two media players. When I press the "play" button, both media players should play at the same time.

When the "play" button is pressed, both media players start to play the same video. But there is a time difference of almost one second between the two videos. How can I remove this time difference? Please help.

My code ;

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void LoadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            axWindowsMediaPlayer2.URL = openFileDialog1.FileName;
           
        }
        
    }

    private void PlayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
        axWindowsMediaPlayer2.Ctlcontrols.play();
        
    }

   

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t = new Timer();
       
        t.Interval = 100;
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
        
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.OpenStateChange += new AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_OpenStateChangeEventHandler(axWindowsMediaPlayer1_OpenStateChange);
    }
    void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        trackBar1.Value = (int)this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition;
    }

    private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_OpenStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_OpenStateChangeEvent e)
    {
        if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.openState == WMPLib.WMPOpenState.wmposMediaOpen)
        {
            trackBar1.Value = 0;
            trackBar1.Maximum = (int)axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentMedia.duration;
            t.Start();

        }
    }

    private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition = trackBar1.Value;
        axWindowsMediaPlayer2.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition = trackBar1.Value;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       

    }
}
```

}